# Suggestion: Display the reputation rate of change for each user

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Hello,

I'd like to suggest that the **rate of change of a user's reputation** be displayed with profiles and signatures. This would be the 1st derivative to the line in the user's reputation graph.

This would encourage new members to participate more and would also show their potential.
Since SO has been going for some years, from the point of view of a newcomer it is impossible to ever reach the top ranks in terms of reputation, but being crowned as a "fast riser" could be a nice motivational prize.

Just my 2c. :-)

Marcelo.

Comment: I disagree that you can't climb in rep, and very highly at that just because SO has been around for a while.  I didn't really have time to answer much until a few months ago, once I did it's not very hard to earn reputation.  Though, a more useful stat I'd like to see is accepted answers or accepted rate percentage (there are DataExlplorer queries for these, if you're curious), it's a better measure of "how many people have you helped" I think, which is more the goal than what rep rank you are :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First derivative over which time frame?  Reputation graphs are not continuous.

I would argue that this is exactly what the graph widget does, although it would be easier to determine the rate of change if it were possible to zoom in on a particular date range.

Comment: Ether, Good point! I should have realized that reputation is not a continuous function. My bad! (Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to vote down my own question) :-) ... Cheers, Marcelo.

Comment: It might be cool to see rate-of-change over 24 hours, 1 week an 1 month though, but I think there's been general resistance to adding more stats on the profile page.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the [Stack Overflow League Tables](http://www.codeka.com.au/Solt/League/SO/2010/8) - a monthly rep league, basically. Just register at the bottom to become part of the league.

EDIT: In terms of putting velocity on the rep graph itself (or as another one) I'd suggest that it would be worth smoothing it over the past 7 days - that's likely to make it a lot more sensible, as it's easier to see trends over a smoothed graph. The individual day graph is likely to be pretty spiky.

Comment: Jon, Thanks for the tip. That's useful, but it is only monthly and it includes only those who chose to register. My suggestion is more for a real time value within SO itself. Cheers, Marcelo.

Answer (score 1):

Reputation leagues are now rolled out:
https://stackexchange.com/leagues

Blog entry:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/network-central-stackexchange-com/